# MySQL sum from two joined tables and multiple rows - need to bring out total or all rows

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I have the following query which works fine when bringing out the total price of each order (thanks to the stackoverflow community):

```
SELECT sum((ordered_items.price + ordered_items.vat) * ordered_items.qty) + orders.postage_price + orders.postage_vat as total_price
FROM orders
JOIN ordered_items
ON orders.id_orders = ordered_items.order_id
GROUP BY orders.id_orders
```

However I also want to bring out the total amount of all the orders added together. I have tried taking off the GROUP BY but this returns the wrong price. I've figured that it's adding up all the items correctly, but then only adding on one postage.

- ordered_items - includes all the items ordered (so there can be multiple rows)
- orders - includes the postage price of the order (there will only ever be one row per order here)

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: it will be helpful if you could share your table structure, some example data the example of desired output.

Comment: you want SUM of `total_price` ?

Comment: Hi, yes I'm looking for the SUM of total_price.

Comment: okay, so the Answer below by BLUEFEET does what you want.
you must have tried it.

Comment: Add table structure and sample data with output as you want , to understand the question

Comment: Just tried the below method and it works great. Thanks for your help Joddy, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something but, can't you just place this in a subquery to get the Total of all orders:

```
SELECT sum(total_price) TotalAllOrders
FROM
(
  SELECT sum((ordered_items.price + ordered_items.vat) * ordered_items.qty) 
         + orders.postage_price + orders.postage_vat as total_price
  FROM orders
  JOIN ordered_items
    ON orders.id_orders = ordered_items.order_id
  GROUP BY orders.id_orders 
) src ;
```

You can also use the group by modifier **[`WITH ROLLUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-modifiers.html)** to have both total sum and sums per order:

```
  SELECT sum((ordered_items.price + ordered_items.vat) * ordered_items.qty) 
         + orders.postage_price + orders.postage_vat as total_price
  FROM orders
  JOIN ordered_items
    ON orders.id_orders = ordered_items.order_id
  GROUP BY orders.id_orders 
    WITH ROLLUP ;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed - thanks. Good solution, clear to understand